# Epplus not able to format the column as number

Tags: c#, epplus

I have assigned the data to a particular column in my code.
Converted the columns as number

```
workSheet.Cells["B3:B11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.00";    
workSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = obj.Number1;
workSheet.Cells["B4"].Value = obj.Number2;
workSheet.Cells["B5"].Value = obj.Number3;
workSheet.Cells["B6"].Value = obj.Number4;
workSheet.Cells["B7"].Value = obj.Number5;
workSheet.Cells["B8"].Value = obj.Number6;
workSheet.Cells["B9"].Value = obj.Number7;
workSheet.Cells["B10"].Value = obj.Number8;
workSheet.Cells["B11"].Value = obj.Number9;
```

When excel is generated, the column are in text format. I want them to be in number format. Need help.

Comment: Are are the `type`s for the Number# properties?  Is this an existing sheet or a new one?  Might want to post more of your code.

Comment: yes obj.Number# are all strings.

Answer (score 1):

If those are `strings` then Epplus/excel will respect that and save them as strings so the formatting you set will be ignored.  You will likely get the green triangles in the corners of the cells indication that they look like numbers.

To treat them as numbers, you need to convert them to `doubles` like this:

```
workSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = Double.Parse(obj.Number1);
```

If you are confident that they will never be null or improperly formatted then the above should be good enough.  Otherwise, might want to do some checks like this:

```
double number;
if (obj.Number1 != null && Double.TryParse(obj.Number1, out number))
    workSheet.Cells["B3"].Value = number;
```

Comment: thankyou for the reply will do the changes and let you know

Comment: This has helped me tremendously. I was posting a number as a string and my NumberFormat was being ignored, thanks for the help.